# Could not load type in symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony, types, load

I have symfony 3.3 and this problem when creating the form.

The error displays when I instantiate the form in the controller.

Here are the classes involved:

**The form.**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Departamento;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;


class DepartamentoType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombreDepartamento',TextType::class)
            ->add('planta', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('edificio',TextType::class)
            ->add('ciudadDepartamento',TextType::class)    
        ;
    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Departamento::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_departamento';
    }


}
```

**The controller.**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Departamento;
use AppBundle\Form\DepartamentoType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DepartamentoController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/departamento_new", name="departamento_new")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $departamento = new Departamento();
        $formulario = $this->createForm(
            DepartamentoType::class, 
            $departamento,
            array('action' => $this->generateUrl('departamento_create'),
                  'method' => 'POST')
        );
        return $this->render('departamento/new_edit.html.twig', [
            'formulario' => $formulario->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Thats how im trying to create form.

This is the error:

> Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\DepartamentoType"
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Comment: what is your value of autoconfigure in services.(yml, php, xml) ?

Comment: @LugiHaue I have no configuration in 'services' relantionship with the form and the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `autoconfigure` option was added in **Symfony 3.3**.

If you're not using `autoconfigure`, make sure to `tag` your service with `form.type`.

For example:

```
app.departamento:
    class: AppBundle\Form\DepartamentoType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

FYI:

With form type service defination, following error fixed.

> Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\DepartamentoType" Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException"

And **(I think)** a special case for @Lucas Leonel Azzollini, he was getting following error.

> Attempted to load class "DepartamentoType" from namespace "AppBundle\Form". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

In his project, DepartamentoType.php file path was in `src\Form`. Then he moved his file in `AppBundle` directory like that: `src\AppBundle\Form`, and error fixed.

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini app/config/services.yml

Comment: Thanks, now I have another error ... "Attempted to load class "DepartamentoType" from namespace "AppBundle\Form".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini what is the full path to DepartamentoType.php ?

Comment: src\Form\DepartamentoType.php

Comment: Why src\Form not src\AppBundle\Form? And what's a point in creating service for type?

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini Your  DepartamentoType class is in AppBundle\Form namespace. But your file path is src\Form.  Can you move that in  AppBundle directory? Like src\AppBundle\Form ?

Comment: @Wolen if you use autoconfigure: true, the container will automatically apply certain configuration to your services, based on your service's class. This is mostly used to auto-tag your services. In other case , you should register it manuely

Comment: I know. but still doesn't understand an idea to creating a service for a type. Never heard about this.

Comment: @Wolen by creating a service you can inject other services into your form types.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any use-case here. He doesn't want to inject service, but he has problems with pass Type to ```createForm()``` function.

Comment: @LugiHaue I have moved the directory and its working now. Thanks you very match for helping me.

Comment: @LugiHaue - You should consider updating your answer and removing the portion about defining a form type service.  It's simply not required unless you feel the urge to inject some additional services into your FormType.  As it stands right not, the answer is very misleading.  The actual answer of course was your suggestion to move the Form directory to the correct location.

Comment: @Cerad, with form type service defination "Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\DepartamentoType" Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException" issue fixed. And it was the main question.

Comment: @LugiHaue Moving the form type file to the correct directory solved the problem.  The manual service definition is not needed and is irrelevant to the question.  Hence the part about your answer being misleading though your edit helps.

Comment: I have been doing a lot of tests and I also read the symfony best practises and it is not neccessary to use the form as a service. For this reason, i removed the configuration in service.yml and the project continues working.

Comment: @LugiHaue can you help me with this issue ? it is very frustrating [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086257/symfony3-how-to-persist-an-object-with-its-collections/48098465?noredirect=1#comment83235243_48098465]