# Symfony3 - How to persist an object with its collections?

Tags: symfony, collections, persist

I have an object "person" with several collections ("documents", "contacts", "etc").
I would like to save "person" and automatically the collection too.
This is my controller:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $persona = new Persona();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(
        PersonaType::class, 
       $persona,
        array('action' => $this->generateUrl('persona_create'),
              'method' => 'POST')
    );

    $formulario->handleRequest($request);

    $em->persist($persona);
    $em->flush();
```

When I dump "$persona", I have the collection and all the information that I need to save, but when I persist it, I lose all the information of the collection except from the "persona" atributtes.

This is one collection of the entity "persona"

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonaContacto", mappedBy="idPersona",cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $contactos;

 public function getContactos() {
return $this->contactos;
```

}

```
public function addContacto(PersonaContacto $persona_contacto) {
    $this->contactos->add($persona_contacto);
}

public function removeContacto(PersonaContacto $persona_contacto) {
    $this->contactos->removeElement($persona_contacto);
}
```

And finally, this is the part of the form when I use the collection

```
->add('contactos', CollectionType::class, array(
                // each entry in the array will be "document" field
                'entry_type' => PersonaContactoType::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                // these options are passed to each "idioma" type
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'contacto-box')
                ),
            ))
```

This is the .js that adds and removes elements. As I said, this .js is used by several collection in the same form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //var collectionCount = 0;

    jQuery('.add-another-collection').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var collectionList = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

        // grab the prototype template
        var newWidget = collectionList.attr('data-prototype');

        // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
        // with a number that's unique to your emails
        // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
        //newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, collectionCount);
        //collectionCount++;

        // create a new list element and add it to the list
        var newTr = jQuery('<tr></tr>').html(newWidget);
        newTr.appendTo(collectionList);

    });

    // handle the removal, just for this example
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-collection', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
})
```

I don´t understand why the cascade persist is not working .

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: @habibun I read the documentation but I don´t understand If I have to save the collection manually or with the "cascade persist" in my entity I avoided that.

Comment: cascade persist,

 can you show your full code

Comment: The unique thing I didn´t show you is get,add and remove methods.... ` public function getContactos() {
    return $this->contactos;
}

public function addContacto(PersonaContacto $persona_contacto) {
    $this->contactos->add($persona_contacto);
}

public function removeContacto(PersonaContacto $persona_contacto) {
    $this->contactos->removeElement($persona_contacto);
}`

Comment: I have just edited the post to show you correctly this methods

Comment: @Lucas , first of all I suggest you to add to your form check if the form is valid. Secondly, I think you wouldn’t have  this problem if you added the collection not to newly created “persona”. I guess you have this issue only when you create the persona. Try to check this out creating persona before rendering the form.

Comment: I check and the form is valid and I also check all you said but I can´t obtain the collections data

Answer (score 0):

Use **mappedBy** in owning side

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonaContacto", mappedBy="xxx", cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
 */
```

Use **inversedBy** in inverse side

```
inversedBy="xxx"
```

More details [Bidirectional Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#bidirectional-associations)

Comment: I continue having the same problem

Comment: I read the documentation but I didn´t find a solution , the .js that add and remove elements could be a problem ?

Comment: I have just added the .js

Comment: I think the problem is not on your js rather mapping or something else because u already get data from the controller.

Comment: I think the same , but I did several things and I continues having the same problem, is frustrating

Comment: updated my answer please check and I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Yes @habibun I did it, but I continue having the same :(

Comment: try to remove 'prototype' => true, from formType

Comment: can you find another thing to do?

Comment: I have my data in persona", the problem is when I persist it, the problem would solve if I persist collection by collection, but I use the orm to symplify this things :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow the doctrine documentation, add a mappedBy prop in your Persona OneToMany annotation and add the ManyToOne in PersonaContacto (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

Then in Persona (may be useless, try it):

```
public function addContacto(PersonaContacto $persona_contacto) {
    $this->contactos->add($persona_contacto);
    $persona_contacto->setPersona($this);
}
```

Comment: I have just added what you said but I continue having the same problem and as I said in the post, when I dump persona just before persist it, I have the collection, but then I loose it

Comment: can you find anything more to do?